# Can I create state variables dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a very simplified version of a React project I'm working on. Basically,  I have a JSON file (called data.json) which contains a property called 'data'. This property contains an array of an unknown amount of objects, and each object has key/value pairs called 'id' and 'value'.

The JSON file is imported into App.js, where I need to create multiple state variables, each based on an object in the array, with the following prerequisites:

1. Each state variable must have a unique name, based on the relevant object's 'id' property (e.g. data1_state, data2_state, etc.)
2. The initial value of each state variable must be equal to the same object's 'value' property
3. Each state variable must be returned as the value of a unique `<input>` field

data.json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "data1",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "id": "data2",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "id": "data3",
            "value": 8
        },
        etc...
        etc...
        etc...
    ]
}
```

This is what I have for App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Data from './data.json';

const data = Data.data;

const App = () => {
  return <>
    {data.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <label>{item.id}: <input type="text" value={/* STATE VARIABLE GOES HERE */} /></label>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>;
}

export default App;
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to write

```
const[item.id + '_state', 'set' + item.id + '_state'] = useState(item.value);
```

for each object in the data array (this way doesn't work). Is this possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "stateful object"?  Do you mean a stateful component?

Comment: I've re-written the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Create another component where you will pass those values as props. You can use those to initialize the state or simply just render them inside.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, using hook.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Data from './data.json';

const data = Data.data;

const App = () => {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(data);
  return <>
    {stateData.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.id}: <strong>{dataX_state}</strong></p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't solve my problem: I need to dynamically create named state variables that I can target individually and I don't see how your solution does that. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I like Aison's answer, but something about it bugs me. I would do it slightly differently.  Fetch the data in component mount (with `useEffect`), then set the state:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./data.json')
      .then(Data => setStateData(Data.data))
  }, [])

  return <>
    {stateData && stateData.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.id}: <strong>{dataX_state}</strong></p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>;
}

export default App;
```

This is a bit more realistic in terms of how data fetching is usually done.

Comment: Thanks, but this only renders a blank screen.

Comment: The issue is probably in using `data` vs `Data.data` or something of the sort.  It will only render if `stateData` exists.  Your initial example used `import Data from './data.json'`, and then you pull out `Data.data`...so just be sure that when you `fetch('./data.json`), that you're getting what you expect, and your `.then(Data=> setStateData(Data.data))` is indeed populating your state variable with some data.  Maybe you need a simple `.then(data => setStateData(data))`?  It depends on how your json is structured.